# How to compare two connectingstrings in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a default connectionstring and a Connectionstring in the webconfig, like this:

```
<add name="BAG_Zipcodes" connectionString="Password=;Persist Security Info=True;
     User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=e;Data Source=" />
```

But if that connectionstring is not in webconfig. use this one:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
```

So I compare it like this:

```
var zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];
            //zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];

if (zipcodeConnection == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"] && zipcodeConnection != null)
    zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];

else if (zipcodeConnection == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName] && zipcodeConnection != null) 
    zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
```

But If I delete this connectionstring from webconfig: add name="BAG_Zipcodes

then the connectionstring is always null.

Thank you

Comment: Is the default connectionstring also places in your `web.config`?

Comment: yes, like this:  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=SFS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=n;Password=" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: And `DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName` is actually "DefaultConnection"? I'm assuming it's some sort of constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using a coalesce statement.

```
var zipcodeConnection = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"])
                      ?? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
```

Comment: Or even better would be the ?? operator

Comment: Why not use the `??` operator?

Answer (score -1):

Oke, I solved like this:

```
var zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];


if (zipcodeConnection == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"] && zipcodeConnection != null)
    zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];

else if (zipcodeConnection == null) 
    zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. What is the purpose of the `if`?